# In what order are files and directories copied when using Linux cp -R?

Tags: linux, file-transfer

If I execute the following command:

```
cp -R /myfiles /mydestination
```

If `myfiles` contains several sub-directories and files, in what order will they be copied?

For example, directories might be named  `0123a, 9993c, myfolder, xfolder`.

They are not copied in alphabetical order OR in date order OR in the order they appear when using a standard `ls` command as far as I can tell, so what actually does determine the order?

Edit: 
  I am trying to determine the order that the cp command uses in order to determine how far along my copy command made it before it stopped.  For example, I was hoping to be able to determine it copied 3 of the 4 directories successfully.

Comment: Remember that the `ls` command by default _sorts the directory contents_ before displaying them.  What you see printed by `ls` is not the actual directory enumeration order.

Comment: Use `ls -U` to get the unsorted directory order. This should be the order that `cp` uses. If you need more control over progress, order, etc., perhaps `cp` is not the tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that they're stored/returned in the filesystem. For "unsorted" filesystems this would generally be their creation order. For "sorted" filesystems (e.g. ext3/4 with `dir_index`) this would be the order used in the filesystem index.

Comment: For unindexed filesystem formats it's a little more complex than that, if one has been deleting directory entries as well as creating them.  (-:

Answer (score 15):

We had EXACTLY the same problem. We copy large amounts of data to and from USB drives and it is annoying to be unable to tell how far through the process it has completed. We instead started using RSYNC.

Instead of using `cp -Rv /source /destination`

Use this instead `rsync -av /source /destination`

Now all of your folders and the contents of them will be processed in alphabetical order and you can easily see how the file copy is progressing.

We have a full description of this solution at our [online backup website](http://www.backup.com.au/Online-Backup-News/linux-how-to-copy-files-in-alphabetical-order.html).

Moderators please note: I posted this once before but it got deleted, perhaps because I did not include enough detail in the answer, or because of the link. Maybe you'll accept this more detailed answer.